# How to configure Xdebug 3 and PhpStorm 2020.3 for collaboration? Ubuntu

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug, xdebug-3

In the instruction write it is necessary to specify simply `xdebug.mode=debug`, which I do in the config file `etc/php/7.4/mods-available/xdebug.ini`, and change port in PhpStorm to 9003. I do the rest of the settings of the PhpStorm as before, but Xdebug does not work. Module Xdebug is on.

What else could be wrong?

Here are screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: 1) Show `xdebug_info()` output (or whole Xdebug section from `phpinfo()`) captured in the same way as you are trying to debug (CLI or a web page). 2) Enable Xdebug log, try to debug then share the log -- it will show where it tries connect to, what the response is etc. 3) Provide your related settings from PhpStorm as well (screenshots)

Comment: Added 8 links to screenshots. I could not normally add here.

Comment: 1) Still need #2 (Xdebug log: `xdebug.log` config param). 2) Xdebug config looks OK (nothing obvious wrong) if it's a local debug (same host). Although you may try `xdebug.client_host = 127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` -- in case if it resolves to IPv6. 3) As I understand Is that's the same local debug and not some docker or alike? 4) Do not configure DBGp Proxy -- you are not using it, at all. 5) The last screenshot -- AFAIK the host should be just `localhost` (instead of current (`localhost:8080`) and port `8080` (instead of current `80`).

Comment: 6) Try adding `xdebug.start_with_request = yes` and see if it will make any difference (restart PHP/web server after making changes). 7) If still nothing -- need to see Xdebug log: it will show where it tries connect to (if it tries at all) , what the response is etc.

Comment: `xdebug.start_with_request = yes` helped! Thank you! My config file now looks like this `zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.start_with_request = yes`   Maybe add something else so that there are no problems in the future?

Comment: It now tries to debug **every single request**, which is inconvenient. Better disable it .. and find the proper solution.

Comment: Please describe how are you debugging: what do you use, what do you press. Do you use Xdebug browser helper (that sets "debug me" Xdebug cookie)?  Check https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/zero-configuration-debugging.html

Comment: I see you are trying to use "PHP Web Page" Run/Debug Configuration -- when invoked from IDE using "Debug" button it should add such "debug me" param (GET param) automatically to the request URL (works for me here on Windows 10, using IIS as a web server). Maybe it's some issue in IDE when 9003 port is used (there is one ticket .. which should not apply to your case .. but just anyway)....? Just try using 9001 or 9002 port instead (in PhpStorm as well as php.ini)

Comment: I launch it like this: put a breakpoint in the desired file, click on the wiretap handset icon. And in the browser I open the desired page. If everything is correct, the xdebug window appears, in it I mainly look at the variables.

Comment: It's not clear if Xdebug browser extension is used here (instead of having `xdebug.start_with_request = yes`). If that's the case, I suggest to get Xdebug browser extension installed and enabled, remove that xdebug option above and when you need to debug some page -- enable "Debug" in that extension -- it will set Xdebug cookie that acts as "debug me" flag. The rest is the same.

Comment: **Benefits:** right now even CLI script (e.g. composer/PHPUnit/etc) or any other PHP activity, Xdebug will try to debug it. Yes, the delay is tiny (around 0.3 sec) but it's there; plus Xdebug will write stuff into the logs (own log .. or even standard PHP error log). It is just having more more control over when/what to debug. Up to you, because if current approach works then no big reason to change it.